# python / numpy - group matrix elements and build dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have two numpy square matrices called M1 and M2 as:

```
M1 = np.matrix('0 1 2 3; 4 5 6 7; 8 9 10 11; 12 13 14 15')

M2 = np.matrix('100 200; 300 400')
```

I would like to group 2x2 elements of M1 assigning those elements to the corresponding element of M2. For instance, the first four elements of M1 grouped should be:

```
g1 = [0,1,4,5]
```

assigned to the value `0` of M2. So that a dictionary would appear as {M1 value: M2 value}:

```
dict1 = {0:100,1:100,4:100,5:100}
```

and so on for the all matrix. The final dictionary would be:

```
dict = {0:100,1:100,4:100,5:100,
        2:200,3:200,6:200,7:200,
        8:300,9:300,12:300,13:300,
        10:400,11:400,14:400,15:400}
```

Since the original matrices are very large, I was looking for some fast numpy/scipy routine.

EDIT: change values of M2 for clarifying the question.

EDIT2: M1 and M2 are always square, and the number of lines/columns of M2 is always half the size of M1.

Comment: could you use other values for M2 to illustrate what the role of M2 is in your final dictionary?

Comment: what happens if M1 and M2 have different sizes than the ones you use here?

Comment: Hi Julien, just add the question with more information, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you asked for some numpy/scipy routine. So this might not be fast enough for your purposes:

```
sh = M2.shape
dic = {M1[2*m+r, 2*n+c]: M2[m, n] for r in xrange(2) for c in xrange(2) for m in xrange(sh[0]) for n in xrange(sh[1])}
print dic
### {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 200, 3: 200, 4: 100, 5: 100, 6: 200, 7: 200, 8: 300, 9: 300, 10: 400, 11: 400, 12: 300, 13: 300, 14: 400, 15: 400}
```

Note: it is best not to name your variable `dict` as it is a built-in type in Python